# How do I install DotNetZip?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, installation, dotnetzip

As I am pretty new to Visual Studio, this question may sound kinda dumb:
How do I install DotNetZip library? I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no setup for DotNetZip.
Simply download  the package from [its site](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/68268), decompress the library somewhere in your disk and set the reference from your project to the release folder appropriate for your project type.  Remember to distribute the DLL with your application.

Another simple way would be to use `nuget` extension to install the library.

Comment: I downloaded the the zip file but no matter how many versions i tried all of those does not seem to extract and I a msg saying it's not a valid archive file.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to add DotNetZip file in your project. I have mention only two ways below:

**Way 1**:
    1. In Visual Studio go to- Tools->NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console
    2. Select your project from Default Project drop-down in Package Manager Console.
    3. Type Install-Package DotNetZip and press enter.
Automatically the package will be included in your project.
Note: Sometime it does not work as expected.

**Way 2:**
    1. In Solution Explorer go to your Project, then References folder.
    2. Right click on References folder -> Manage NuGet Packages.
    3. On the pop up window select Online from left menu.
    4. Type DotNetZip on Seach text box.
    5. From loaded list click Install button.
[Manage NugGet Package PopUp window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atrkM.png)